# Insert values from a Dataframe into another Dataframe, both DF's indexed on dates

Tags: pandas

I have `df1`:

```
                     GOOG  AAPL  XOM  IBM  _CASH
2011-01-13 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-14 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-18 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-19 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-20 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
...
```

and `df2`:

```
    year  month  day symbol order_type  shares  trans_date
0   2011      1   13   AAPL       Sell    1500  2011-01-13
1   2011      1   13    IBM        Buy    4000  2011-01-13
2   2011      1   26   GOOG        Buy    1000  2011-01-26
3   2011      2    2    XOM       Sell    4000  2011-02-02
4   2011      2   10    XOM        Buy    4000  2011-02-10
5   2011      3    3   GOOG       Sell    1000  2011-03-03
6   2011      3    3    IBM       Sell    2200  2011-03-03
7   2011      6    3    IBM       Sell    3300  2011-06-03
8   2011      5    3    IBM        Buy    1500  2011-05-03
9   2011      6   10   AAPL        Buy    1200  2011-06-10
10  2011      8    1   GOOG        Buy      55  2011-08-01
11  2011      8    1   GOOG       Sell      55  2011-08-01
12  2011     12   20   AAPL       Sell    1200  2011-12-20
```

I want to insert the `df2` 'shares' value into the matching `df1` date row and `df1` matching symbol column. The sign of the 'shares' value will be positive for a 'buy' 'order_type' and negative for a 'Sell'

For example, for the first row of `df2` a value of -1500 will be inserted in the 'AAPL' column of `df1`, the row matched on `df2` 'trans_date' and `df1` timestamp.

Both `df2` 'trans_date' and `df1` timestamp are indexed.

I am grateful for your assistance.

I stacked df1 and merged with df2 using this:

pd.merge(df_stacked_mx, df_orders, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')

I got this:

```
 level_0             level_1  0  year  month  day symbol order_type  shares  \
0  2011-01-13 16:00:00    GOOG  0  2011      1   13   AAPL       Sell    1500   
1  2011-01-13 16:00:00    AAPL  0  2011      1   13    IBM        Buy    4000   
2  2011-01-13 16:00:00     XOM  0  2011      1   26   GOOG        Buy    1000   
3  2011-01-13 16:00:00     IBM  0  2011      2    2    XOM       Sell    4000   
4  2011-01-13 16:00:00   _CASH  0  2011      2   10    XOM        Buy    4000   
5  2011-01-14 16:00:00    GOOG  0  2011      3    3   GOOG       Sell    1000   
6  2011-01-14 16:00:00    AAPL  0  2011      3    3    IBM       Sell    2200   
7  2011-01-14 16:00:00     XOM  0  2011      6    3    IBM       Sell    3300   
8  2011-01-14 16:00:00     IBM  0  2011      5    3    IBM        Buy    1500   
9  2011-01-14 16:00:00   _CASH  0  2011      6   10   AAPL        Buy    1200   
10 2011-01-18 16:00:00    GOOG  0  2011      8    1   GOOG        Buy      55   
11 2011-01-18 16:00:00    AAPL  0  2011      8    1   GOOG       Sell      55   
12 2011-01-18 16:00:00     XOM  0  2011     12   20   AAPL       Sell    1200   


            trans_date  
0  2011-01-13 16:00:00  
1  2011-01-13 16:00:00  
2  2011-01-26 16:00:00  
3  2011-02-02 16:00:00  
4  2011-02-10 16:00:00  
5  2011-03-03 16:00:00  
6  2011-03-03 16:00:00  
7  2011-06-03 16:00:00  
8  2011-05-03 16:00:00  
9  2011-06-10 16:00:00  
10 2011-08-01 16:00:00  
11 2011-08-01 16:00:00  
12 2011-12-20 16:00:00
```

I have no idea where to go next and I need assistance.

Drew

Thank you Bob for your GitHub contribution. Very elegant and no looping. it would have taken me an age to get to the answer.

There is one problem. The stacked df1 update returns "None". The indices are not matching:

My stacked df2 looks like this:

```
trans_date           symbol
2011-01-13 16:00:00  AAPL     -1500
                     IBM       4000
2011-01-26 16:00:00  GOOG      1000
2011-02-02 16:00:00  XOM      -4000
2011-02-10 16:00:00  XOM       4000
2011-03-03 16:00:00  GOOG     -1000
                     IBM      -2200
2011-05-03 16:00:00  IBM       1500
2011-06-03 16:00:00  IBM      -3300
2011-06-10 16:00:00  AAPL      1200
2011-08-01 16:00:00  GOOG         0
2011-12-20 16:00:00  AAPL     -1200
```

Yours is:

```
trans_date  symbol
2011-01-13  AAPL     -1500
            IBM       4000
2011-01-26  GOOG      1000
2011-02-02  XOM      -4000
2011-02-10  XOM       4000
2011-03-03  GOOG     -1000
            IBM      -2200
2011-05-03  IBM       1500
2011-06-03  IBM      -3300
2011-06-10  AAPL      1200
2011-08-01  GOOG         0
2011-12-20  AAPL     -1200
Name: shares, dtype: int64
```

Notice mine has a time in the date.

But my df1 does not have the time in the date:

```
                GOOG  AAPL  XOM  IBM  _CASH
2011-01-13     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-26     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-02     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-10     0     0    0    0      0
2011-03-03     0     0    0    0      0
2011-05-03     0     0    0    0      0
2011-06-03     0     0    0    0      0
2011-06-10     0     0    0    0      0
2011-08-01     0     0    0    0      0
2011-12-20     0     0    0    0      0
```

This is confusing. If I create a df using all timestamps between a start and enddate I get the time stamps:

```
                   GOOG  AAPL  XOM  IBM  _CASH
2011-01-13 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-14 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-18 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-19 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-20 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-21 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-24 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-25 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-26 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-27 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-28 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-01-31 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-01 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-02 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-03 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-04 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-07 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-08 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-09 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-10 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-11 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-14 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-15 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-16 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-17 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-18 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-22 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-23 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-24 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
2011-02-25 16:00:00     0     0    0    0      0
                  ...   ...  ...  ...    ...
```

However if I create a df with just the dates in df2, the time component is dropped ????:

I am in datetime hell Bob as you can probably tell.

An obvious solution is to make both indices the date-with-time format but I do not know how to do this for the df1 file. Also note that dropping the time component in the df2 index is not an option. This df has to be eventually merged with the larger df that contains all the datetimes between start/end, i.e. the one that has the time in the date.

A million thanks for your effort on my behalf Bob.

Comment: Drew, I would probably use [Pandas' Stack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) on df1 like so `df1.stack()` and then [Merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two frames.  That should get you pretty close

Comment: Thank you Bob. I will give it a try.

Comment: Looks like it didn't line up quite right because your indexes aren't aligned.  What is the result of `df2.index`?

Comment: Also, how do you intend to handle multiple rows for the same day and symbol?  eg GOOG has two rows for 8/1/11

Comment: Thanks Bob for the quick reply. The index parameters for df2 are "return pd.TimeSeries(index=dates, data=dates)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=13, step=1)" . The more I look at this I think that the only way to go is iterate through df2 and pass each row's column values to a function that searches df1 for a date match and replaces df1 column values. a with appropriate logic to handle the "GOOG" type transactions.

Comment: Drew, take a look at this [example](https://github.com/bobhaffner/stock_dates_symbols/blob/master/stock_dates_symbols.ipynb)